# How can I add OnClickListener to Drawable in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have edittext and want to add to right "search" icon..

```
searchTxt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.search, 0);
```

But how can I add event for click this icon?

```
searchTxt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Drawable co = ((TextView) v).getCompoundDrawables()[2];

    if (event.getX() > v.getMeasuredWidth() - v.getPaddingRight()
                     - co.getIntrinsicWidth()) {
        Datas.search = searchTxt.getText().toString();
            startActivity(Search.class);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }

});
```

??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drawables are non-interactive elements, so you cannont set a click listener on a drawable.
A simple solution would be putting an `ImageView` containing the "search" icon over the `EditText` and adding a right padding on the `EditText` so the text doesn't overlap with the icon.

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText ...
              android:paddingRight="..."
              ... />
    <ImageView ...
               android:src="@drawable/search"
               android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
               ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to connect your listener with the resource id of your button or image.

actually you can make an image into a button. or just replace the button with your image.
you add a selector in res/drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/yourImage" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/yourImagePressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/yourImagePressed" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/yourImage" />
```

then add to your layout

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/yourButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_selector"
    android:text="@string/yourStr"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
```

you would then tie the image in source with the button id

Comment: findViewById(R.drawable.search).setOnClickListener(this);  ?

Comment: @fernando sor: This more a comment than a real answer. Please  provide a code example. Possibly add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

well i would suggest instead of doing all these you can just add alignLeft,alignTop,alignBottom,alignTop tags into the image view you are using like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_view_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/edt_text_search"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/edt_text_search"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/edt_text_search"
        android:src="@drawable/search_selected"
        android:padding="2dp" />
```

edt_text_search is the id of the edittext